# change number to number to currency and Human-friendly format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to convert some digits to currency and human friendly format in `ruby on rails`.

i know it could be done like this `number_to_currency(number_to_human(4000000))` but for some reason im trying to do it like this.

eg. `something like this 4000000.to_s(:human).to_s(:currency) => "$4 Million"`

it this possible somehow ?

Comment: Obvious question: why? You already have the helpers that allow you to do that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`number_to_human`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human).

```
number_to_currency(number_to_human(4000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this code in en.yml as the following:

```
number:
 currency:
  format:
    delimiter: ! ','
    format: ! '%u%n'
    precision: 2
    separator: .
    significant: false
    strip_insignificant_zeros: false
    unit: $
 format:
  delimiter: ! ','
  precision: 3
  separator: .
  significant: false
  strip_insignificant_zeros: false
 human:
  decimal_units:
    format: ! '%n %u'
    units:
      billion: Billion
      million: Million
      quadrillion: Quadrillion
      thousand: Thousand
      trillion: Trillion
      unit: ''
  format:
    delimiter: ''
    precision: 3
    significant: true
    strip_insignificant_zeros: true
```

and write the following code:

```
number_to_currency(number_to_human(4000000))
```

read about number_to_human from these: [link_1](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human), and [link_2](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml)